Next js 14 with CKEditor 5 build error: e.createElement is not a function
I'm experiencing a build error while building a Next.js 14, on a page with CKEditor.
I narrowed it down to the editor component for sure.
Error is:
TypeError: e.createElement is not a function
I read about dynamic rendering on Stackoverflow but that it works on Next.js 13, and it did actually not worked for me.
How do I solve this?

Does anyone know the answer?

Add
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

At the top of the page, I tried adding it randomly and it didn't work first but it should be at the top of it.
